# Can't access CouchDB Futon interface on Amazon EC2 server

Tags: amazon-ec2, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I followed the installation instructions from this page: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-couchdb-and-futon-on-ubuntu-14-04

I then changed the ownership of /etc/couchdb from root to ubuntu so that i can edit the local.ini file.

I then changed the bind address in the local.ini file to 0.0.0.0 so that I can access the Futon interface on an external IP. The port is still the same.

I then restarted CouchDB but I can't access Futon no matter what.

Any help?

Comment: Can you access it internally?

Comment: No. I can retrieve some basic information using curl. When I try to access futon using SSH tunneling, i get a permission denied error.

Comment: You opened the port in Inbound rules of the Security Group attached to that Instance?

Comment: If you change the bind address to 0.0.0.0 then you don't need a tunnel to access futon (or couchdb in general). If you can curl it remotely and get basic info then you should also be able to access the futon url by just adding _util, e.g. http://IPADDRESS:5984/_utils